# Ubuntu 14.04 Software Updater crashes

Tags: apt, updates, 14.04, update-manager

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 and I tried to update it because I could not mount my SD-card while my external HDD worked But when I tried to open my software updater it crashed immediately. Same happened with synaptic package manager and with the `apt-get update` command in the terminal. The terminal obviously did not crash but the same error was displayed.

They all put out: `SystemError'>(E:Malformed line 56 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse))`

Comment: So what's on line 56 in `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Use `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and press CTRL + C to check the line you're currently on.

Comment: that is what is written in line 56:deb http://archive.canonical.com/trusty partner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out line 56 (place a `#` in front of it).

On a new line, enter the following rule:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Save the file using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Run `sudo apt-get update` to verify that the problem has been solved.

Comment: it all worked great, but at the end one link coud not be found: http://archive.canonical.com/uuntu/dists/trusty/partner/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]     But that's something else, is it?

Comment: You're missing Ubuntu's `b`.

Comment: oops, yeah that did it. Works great now thanks :)

Comment: Great! Also, please use code tags for output next time, this makes things easier to read.